# Заполнять Google Sheets по получению письма

Tags: gmail, автоматизация, google-spreadsheet

Нужно заполнять Google Sheets, если пришло письмо.
Требования такие:
Есть группа email-адресов.
Есть документ в Google Sheets.
Есть строки в Google Sheets, с полям "имя" "номер".
Нужно проверять от кого письмо, находить в Google Sheet данный контакт и проставлять у этой строки в поле "номер" единицу под номером, пришедшим в названии письма от этого контакта.
По русски - ученик отправляет домашнее задание, в теме письма его номер, необходимо в таблице в поле с его именем проставлять единицу в поле под номером домашки.

Какие есть решения?
Сейчас изучаю рецепты в IFTTT\Zapier, но похоже, они умеют только вещи попроще, такие как добавить запись с данными о письме (отправитель, тема и т.д.) на новую строку в таблицу. Есть мысли собирать все это на одной странице, а на другой, если это возможно, вести учет (добавлять единицу под числом, если пришло письмо с таким числом. если такое вообще возможно из коробки).
Также слышал, что есть язык скриптов в Google Sheets.
Какие еще есть решения? Может быть другие сервисы по автоматизации, библиотеки, и т.д.?

Answer (score 0):

> слышал, что есть язык скриптов в Google Sheets

Правильно слышали. Это и есть ключ к решению. Более точно и подробно описано в [официальном руководстве](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Готовое решение по понятным причинам представить не могу, хоть и приходилось делать подобные задачи.